# Can't access nested dictionaries/arrays from json with swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, dictionary

I am trying to access ["upper category"]["first category"][0][0] of local json file

```
{
    "upper category": {
        "first category": [
            [
                "this is a question", 
                "this is an answer", 
                "this is the rank"
            ], 
            [
                "this is a question2", 
                "this is an answer2", 
                "this is the rank2"
            ]
        ], 
        "second category": [
            [
                "this is a question3", 
                "this is an answer3", 
                "this is the rank3"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

with

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
do {let data:NSData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
```

I am not able to access anything beyond the first dictionary.

I tried several times with options like (I tried multiple older solutions but they don't seem to work for me, maybe swift 3)

```
    if let description = ((((json?["upper category"] as? AnyObject)?["first category"] as? AnyObject)?[0] as? AnyObject)?[0] as? String) {
```

It is likely a noob question, I am new to ios. While any answer extremely appreciated explaining how to write code for other number of nested types would be best

(xcode 8, swift 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit overkill but you can cast the json to `[String:[String:[[String]]]]`

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(...) as? [String:[String:[[String]]]]
```

Otherwise, if for example, the dictionary contains elements other than a nested dictionary, you will just have to cast the top level dictionary to `[String:Any]` and cast the nested elements individually.

```
if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(...) as? [String:Any] {

    let foo = json["foo"] as? Int
    let bar = json["bar"] as? [String:Any]

    ...
}
```

Comment: What if my son object is not homogenous and only one of the element of the dictionary is a nested dictionary? I can't cast it as [String: [String: Any]]. And I cannot get a nested dictionary just as the OP

Comment: @rommex you will have to cast the nested elements individually in that case, I have updated my answer to cover this scenario.